# Debian Wheezy, apt-get have unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

Pretty much any comand that I try that involves `apt-get` gives me an error that tells me I should run `apt-get -f install`, but that gives me this error:

```
root@vps148794:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-4.7 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 g++-4.7 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 gcc-4.7 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-dev : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Seems like `gcc-4.7` missing is the problem, but if I try `apt-get install gcc-4.7`

```
root@vps148794:~# apt-get install gcc-4.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gcc-4.7 is already the newest version.
gcc-4.7 set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-4.7 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 g++-4.7 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 gcc-4.7 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 libgomp1 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-dev : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Why is this happening? How do I bring back apt-get so that I can install things? I'm completely blocked from installing as this error comes up with anything I try to install. Maybe this can help?

```
root@vps148794:~# apt-cache policy gcc-4.7 g++-4.7
gcc-4.7:
  Installed: 4.7.2-5
  Candidate: 4.7.2-5
  Version table:
 *** 4.7.2-5 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
g++-4.7:
  Installed: 4.7.2-5
  Candidate: 4.7.2-5
  Version table:
 *** 4.7.2-5 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


root@vps148794:~# apt-cache policy gcc-4.7-base
gcc-4.7-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.7.2-5
  Version table:
     4.7.2-5 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
#deb http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic universe
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

Comment: You do realise that Debian Wheezy is completely unsupported these days?

Comment: What does your `/etc/apt/sources.list` loo ḱ like? What does `apt-cache policy gcc-4.7-base` say?

Comment: Cache policy is in the question. sources.list will be in 10 seconds, forgot to mention it. Thanks!

Comment: I'd really prefer not to reboot and/or update the VPS, as long as I'm able to run apt-get with Wheezy-compatible packages I'm fine. Though, I'm aware I'll need to update debian in the future.

Comment: `apt-cache policy` output is only in the question for two packages. I'm asking about another.

Comment: Oh! My bad... running it now, just a sec!

Comment: You are right! installing "gcc-4.7-base" works, while only "gcc-4.7" is not the same thing. I thought the opposite and didn't try it. Thanks! Wanna post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really think about what you're doing here. Debian Wheezy is completely unsupported these days, and at some point (I don't remember if it has been announced when) it will be removed from the (main) mirrors.

The answer lies in the difference between `gcc-4.7` which is installed and `gcc-4.7-base` which the edit shows isn't. Installing that should help. (I can't really explain how you ended up in that situation.)

Another thing: I don't know what is/was in that izzysoft.de repo, but it seems to be made for ubuntu, it can be quite dangerous to mix repositories like that.